# Which test for inter-group and intra-group significance?

Tags: anova

It's been a while since I had my statistics but if I recall there should be a test that I can run on data structured as follows:

```
    cat1        cat2        cat3        Group
0   312.621145  293.584362  382.129353  o
1   264.965909  196.390110  312.721461  y
2   450.178161  291.210000  357.659341  y
3   171.512367  178.749077  200.645902  o
4   341.158879  301.321839  268.037037  y
// More data...
```

The question would be if there are significant differences between the means within a category, factored by the group, and over the categories for a given group.

I'm not sure, is this ANOVA or Multi-ANOVA (if at all)?

---

Addition

The data is structured as follows: there are two groups of particants, `o` and `y`. Every row corresponds to one participant. For every participant three values are recorded (`cat1`, `cat2` and `cat3`).

As an example, the mean of `cat1` for group `o` could be formed by filtering all `o` entries and then forming the mean of the `cat1` values.

---

Addition 2
Essentially, the when forming the averages for the categories by group, the averages can be plotted as such:

[image: plot]

I'd now be interested in seeing if the "intra" group difference (1) and the inter-group (2) differences are statistically significant. In the example plot, only one intra-group difference is indicated, but of course the differences within groups "cat2" and "cat3" would also be of interest. Also the Intergroup differences for the blue values would be interesting.

Comment: what is represented by 0,1,2 ...

Comment: Its the pandas row index, thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Does the data represent group (rows) and category( columns) and mean estimates ? Not discernable ! please elaborate.

Comment: I added explanations to the question text. @SubhashC.Davar

Comment: what are your objectives ?

Comment: Dear @SubhashC.Davar I have added an illustration to better explain my question.